# Issues with Push Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm having an issue where the occurs reads "'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'SignUpSegue'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController."

I'm new to iOS development but I've done the research on this issue and one of the common ones is embedding in a navigation controller which i do.I have an initial view controller, the log in page, embedded inside a navigation controller with also a button which segues to a sign up page that is pushed.  When the user signs on, I test it by logging out and my goal is to go back to the log in page.  I modally present the log in page when the user logs out and the log in page appears perfectly.  I can sign on again but if i happen to press sign up, it takes offense and displays the error.  Note that the sign up page normally works which is why im curious it issues an alarm after being modally presented after logging out. The segues are all titled properly and connected  There's a segue connecting the log in page and the sign up page and a segue connecting the log out page to the log in page.

A side question, when I modally present the log in page after logging out, should my destinationviewcontroller be the log in view or the navigation controller it is embedded in.
I appreciate any help greatly and if any more information is needed I will gladly add it.

Here's the relevant code for the log in page, logInViewController

```
// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
// Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SignInSegue"]){
    HomeTab *logIn=[segue destinationViewController];
}
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SignUpSegue"]){
    SignUpView *signUp=[segue destinationViewController];
}
}


- (IBAction)logInUser:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"Log In Attempted");
if([self fieldsEmpty]){
    UIAlertView *signIn=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Empty Field(s)" message:@"Please make sure all fields are filled out" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [signIn show];
}

else{
    [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:UserName.text password:Password.text block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error)
     {
         /*Successful sign in, go to home page*/
         if(!error){
             [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SignInSegue" sender:sender];
         }
         else{
             UIAlertView *signIn=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Fail" message:@"Your username and password failed to match.\nPlease try again" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [signIn show];
         }
     }];
}
}

- (IBAction)signUpUser:(id)sender {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SignUpSegue" sender:sender];
}
```

And here is the relevant code when signing out on a different view controller (Settings.m)

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
// Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"logOutSegue"]){
    LogInViewController *logIn=[segue destinationViewController];
}

}


- (IBAction)logOutCurrentUser:(id)sender {
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Are You Sure?" message:@"If you would like to log out press continue, if not press cancel" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
[alert show];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if(buttonIndex==0){
    [PFUser logOut];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"logOutSegue" sender:self];
}
if(buttonIndex==1){
    return;
}
}
```

Comment: If you do a push from the login page to the sign up page, you should go back to login with popViewControllerAnimated:, not by presenting the login controller. A pop undoes a push, and a dismiss undoes a presentation; those things go together in pairs. Also, never go back to a controller with a segue, unless you're using an unwind segue; other segues always instantiate new controllers, so you aren't really going back, you're just creating a new instance.

Comment: For your first error, if you're using Storyboards, you'll need to set the segue identifier in the properties pane.

Comment: So would I need an unwind segue to logout . My log in page modally presents the home user interface where there is a logout option